# Getting my career on track - are tertiary quals better than self taught?

Tags: learning, certification, fresher

I'm a career changer and have been doing the Freecodecamp syllabus alongside with working on a few hobby projects which have required me to learn SQL and PHP.

**My Goal**

Ultimately, I want to work in software or web development and working towards something like database administration. I have also considered security as it seems to be in demand, but I would like to work in the software side of security, rather than in infrastructre.

**My Issue**

I have been offered a course in Cyber Security and Networking - which is a 6 month course and covers Intro to Cyber Security, Networking and Routing and Project Management. The Cyber Security component follows the Cisco 'Intro to Cyber Security' - I'm not sure whether this is what I am looking for as it seems that it is more based on hardware and configuration.

I am trying to build my GitHub and continue learning, but I'm just not sure whether it will ever be enough.

**My Questions**

- Is any tertiary qualification better than self taught?
- If I want to do DBA or software security, is learning networking and routing worthwhile?
- Are the qualifications that would be better suited to what I am looking for?

Cheers for any help, I don't really have many contacts in the industry and COVID has ceased the ability to build my network.

Comment: You know, things like Freecodecamp are unfortunately "laughable" at best. Defintely do them if you want to, but, don't expect it to be worth anything "on a resume".

Answer (score 1):

Qualifications are always better that self taught as they offer proof you learned to a certain standard.

For your chosen career goal then understanding networking will be very valuable.

Comment: But tertiary qualifications are easier to fake than self-taught with visible projects. Especially when the certificates cost money and the provider has an incentive for you to pass easily.

Answer (score 1):

> Is any tertiary qualification better than self taught?

If you can demonstrate via Github what you have learned then you would not need to go down the route of tertiary qualification. If you can become active in open source groups that will also be valuable. See my reply below in regard to certification route.

> If I want to do DBA or software security, is learning networking and
> routing worthwhile?

You don't need to know about routing/networking to become a DBA. It is a lot more useful for a security expert role.

> Are the qualifications that would be better suited to what I am
> looking for?

Why not look at certifications? There are different paths you can follow in order to obtain your first role. If it is e.g. 'Microsoft' certified it will have a much more focused content and it will show that you have learned the basic skills to be productive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @fran, I appreciate it. I think that following the certifications and actual practice paths through Github is probably the way to go for me at the moment.

Comment: Your welcome, stick with it and I hope you get the position you want